# Copying data from one worksheet to specified worksheet in another workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

So I have one tedious task at work which involves updating one excel file with new data extracted from different systems that I'd love to have automated.

This looks like that:
new_workbook[sheet1] -> pasted to the end of target_workbook[sheet1]

Format and shape of the columns is exactly the same.

I am familiar with xlwings api.copy as here

```
import xlwings as xw

source = r'source.xlsx'
target = r'target.xlsx'

wb = xw.Book(source)
sht = wb.sheets[0]

new_wb = xw.Book(target)
new_sht = new_wb.sheets[0]

sht.api.Copy(None, After=new_sht.api)

new_wb.save()
new_wb.close()
```

But this would create new worksheet in target workbook and paste the data there, not in already existing one. Is there any way to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this iterative solution will be helpful for you.

```
#import modules
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#read data from source path
df=pd.read_excel(source)

#load workbook and create sheet 
wb=load_workbook(target)
ws=wb.create_sheet("new_worksheet")

#add values in df iteratively to sheet named ws
for row in dataframe_to_rows(df,index=False,header=True):
    ws.append(row)
#save and close workbook
wb.save(target)
wb.close()
```